# How to know which node is connected as input on editprepare

Tags: node-red

I am trying to pass some data from previous node to current node, which can be used to set a checkbox  oneditprepare event,
Is there any way to know which node is connected or wired as input to your current node oneditprepare event.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple answer: no.

A node does not know what it is connected to - the runtime takes care of that.

Comment: So there is no way we can makeout which node is connected oneditprepare? until runtime payload is injected?